# Java map, key = class, value = instance of that class

Tags: java, parameterized

I'm not sure what I want to do is possible, but if it is, I want to find out how. Basically, I want to create a Map where the key is a class (`java.lang.Class`), and value for that entry is an instance of that class. Currently I have

```
private Map<Class<?>, Object> myMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
```

However, this means any Object can be placed in the Map. If it is possible, I want to make it, so only an instance of the class in the key can be placed in the map. Is there any way to use the ? parametrization on the Class to ensure this?

Also, I found there could be a [possible memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625546/is-using-the-class-instance-as-a-map-key-a-best-practice) when doing something like this. I'm not sure I fully understand how this happens. I will only be sticking singleton objects into the map, so would there still be concern for a memory leak? If so, how do I prevent it?

Comment: With what I'm doing, it isn't critical that I ensure this. I was just wanting to know if it was possible. It's good to know all this for future reference though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java's type system is simply not strong enough to enforce the type constraint you're describing directly, and you'll need to do some unsafe casts to make this work -- or wrap the `Map` in some other API that enforces the type safety.  [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.java) does just that for exactly this use case, providing an externally safe API that imposes additional restrictions on the `Map` interface to make it work.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

The only time this can cause a memory leak is if there's some classes you're using here that would not be retained for the life of the application.  This isn't a concern for many users, especially if you're writing a "server side" application that isn't as concerned about unloading unused classes.

Comment: Given this, maybe a simplistic solution is to extend HashMap and override the put method to enforce that the value is from the same class as the key.

Comment: I have to admit I mostly don't like that solution because you'll still have to do casts and everything, and you don't get the benefits of type safety at compile time.

Comment: +1 for "or wrap the Map in some other API that enforces the type safety" (and for contributing to Guava :) But can't you do this with a simple Class.cast() (see my answer below)?

Comment: That's essentially what you'd be doing, yes, and that's basically what `ClassToInstanceMap` does internally.

Answer (score 18):

What you are using is a **[heterogeneous container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139325/heterogeneous-container-to-store-genericly-typed-objects-in-java)**. These **can** be made typesafe by using type tokens (as you already do) and `Class.cast()` with the correct application logic: So there is an unchecked suppressWarning within `Class.cast()`, but the application logic guarantees correctness.

I advise you read Josh Bloch's Effective Java Item 29: Consider typesafe heterogeneous containers. His example is:

```
// Typesafe heterogeneous container pattern - implementation
public class Favorites {
  private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites =
    new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

  public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
    if (type == null)
      throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
    favorites.put(type, instance);
  }

  public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(favorites.get(type));
  }
}
```

---

I only see a possibility for **memory leakage** if you hold arbitrarily many different types you actually no longer need.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. No need to rely on 3rd party libs. Cheers

Answer (score 10):

You can hide the collection and only allow it to be accessed via accessor methods.

```
private final Map<Class, Object> myMap = new HashMap<Class, Object>();

public <T> void putMap(Class<T> tClass, T t) {
     myMap.put(tClass, t);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getMap(Class<T> tClass) {
    return (T) myMap.get(tClass);
}
```

The warning can be ignored as you know the cast in the last method is safe even if the compiler does not.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible due to type erasure.

However, you could subclass `HashMap` and write some logic into the `put` method which will do this for you:

```
public void put(K key, V value) {

    if  ( // value is an instance of key using .getClass()) { 
        super.put(key, value)
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

(Code for illustrative purposes only)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. I solved it using the below code :

```
interface Service { }

class ServiceCache {
private HashMap<Class<? extends Service>, Service> services;

public ServiceCache() {
    services = new HashMap<>();
}

public <T extends Service> T getService(Class<T> service) {
    if (services.containsKey(service))
        return (T) services.get(service);
    return null;
}

public <T extends Service> void addService(T service, Class<? extends Service> serviceInterface) {
    services.put(serviceInterface, service);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clazz.isInstance(TypeClass.class)` can be used to compare types.
According to the documentation `public native boolean isInstance(Object obj)` method

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language **instanceof** operator. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this Class object without raising a ClassCastException. It returns false otherwise.

`clazz.isAssignableFrom(TypeClass.class)` can be used to compare both super and sub types.
According to the documentation `public native boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)` method

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.