# Java 8 generic map of functions

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Not sure if this is even possible; I admit I am not as good at generics as I would like to be.

Basically, I want to create a map of class -> function
where the class used for the key is the class of the input to the function, like such (not legal syntax):

```
public static Map<Class<T>,Function<T,Expression>> STUFF = new HashMap<>();

{
    STUFF.put(List.class, ListExpression::new);
    STUFF.put(String.class, StringExpression::new);// this constructor must take string
}
```

so that if I do:

```
Function<String,Expression> e = STUFF.get(o.getClass());
Expression ex = e.apply(o);
```

It gets the types right for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194855/java-map-key-class-value-instance-of-that-class

Comment: I think you need to override `put` in HashMap to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be done. Every time you want `Map<Class<T>, SomeType<T>>`, ie associating a class with a parameterized type somehow related to the class in the key, it can't be done. This is because the key type, `Class<T>` must be shared among all entries as per the `Map<K, V>` definition.

What remains is the practical alternative to have a `Map<Class<?>, SomeType<?>>`, encapsulate this map in a private field and check constraints when putting items in the map. Something like

```
public class StuffManager {

  private final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> stuff = new HashMap<>();

  public <T> void register(Class<T> key, Consumer<? super T> val) {
    stuff.put(key, val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason I couldn't just class StuffManager<T> implements Map<Class<T>, Function<T,Expression> then use delegation?

Comment: @Christian Bongiorno you can't have a type parameter in the manager because each entry in the map has its own, different class

Comment: @Radiodef I don't think so. When you get your expression via Object.class, that expression evaluates to String as per your example, which is Object-compatible, hence no ClassCastException is thrown. By the way, PECS is just stupid: it was invented solely to explain collections to people who couldn't understand generics, but there are no collections here (map is irrelevant). I think "super" may make sense too, but it all depends on the actual types of the OP program

Comment: If T is the type of the input the code needs to be fixed. I was not particularly interested in it since it does not change the matter of the question (you may notice I used a fictionary Function type with just one type parameter, not the Java 8 one), and don't know where your StringExpression comes from - but the name implies it builds a String somehow. PECS is not a technical argument: you can't say "this is wrong because PECS" . This is wrong because OP explicitly stated it was input while I assumed output in my answer and that was misleading. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Radiodef btw, I obviously did **not** mean "PECS stupid = you stupid". I dislike approaches like PECS because they are non technical and encourage a "don't tell me why, just show me how" development

Answer (score 3):

If you use something like Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) then you can do this in a type-safe way but still unchecked.

```
class ExpressionMap {
    private final Map<TypeToken<?>, Function<?, Expression>> m =
        new HashMap<>();

    <T> void put(TypeToken<T> type, Function<T, Expression> f) {
        m.put(type, f);
    }

    <T> Function<T, Expression> get(TypeToken<T> type) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Function<T, Expression> f =
            (Function<T, Expression>) m.get(type);
        return f;
    }
}

static ExpressionMap stuff = ExpressionMap();
static {
    stuff.put(new TypeToken<List>() {}, ListExpression::new);
    stuff.put(new TypeToken<String>() {}, StringExpression::new);
}
```

You can use a `Class` instead of `TypeToken` but the problem is that it breaks down with generic types.

If you had a

```
ListStringExpression extends Expression {
    ListStringExpression(List<String> l) {}
}
```

you can't have a `Class<List<String>>` so all `ListOfSomeTypeExpression::new` get lumped together as `Function<List, Expression>`. It's not safe.

You could do this:

```
ExpressionMap em = new ExpressionMap();
em.put(List.class, ListStringExpression::new);
// causing heap pollution
// subtly passing List<Integer> to List<String>
Expression ex =
    em.get(List.class).apply(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

So it's possible but beware the caveats.

---

Also see [*What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this with the default `Map` interface.

But you can of course 'hide' the map behind a facade - a custom interface or class that provides specific methods to the user:

```
public <T> Function<T, Expression> getFunction(Class<T> key) {
    // implement using generic Map<Class<?>, Function<?, Expression>
}
```

or even:

```
public Expression apply(Object param);
```