# Fun with Generics; Type-Safe HashMap<Class<?>, CachedObject<?>>

Tags: java, generics

PrinterService has a generic `getAttribute` function that uses a Class argument to determine the type of attribute returned. Due to a memory leak in java (JDK-7001133) we are caching these values. Most of the caches were trivial to implement, but getAttribute was not. I add them to an ArrayList, indexed by the class of the request. The issue is I wasn't able to find a type-safe way of doing it. In the following example, I get a warning about an unsafe cast.

In reality, the cast is safe, so worst case scenario I will just use my example, I was curious to see if there is a better way.

```java
    private final HashMap<Class<?>, CachedObject<?>> cachedAttributes = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends PrintServiceAttribute> T getAttribute(Class<T> category) {
        if (!cachedAttributes.containsKey(category)) {
            Supplier<T> supplier = () -> innerPrintService.getAttribute(category);
            CachedObject<T> cachedObject = new CachedObject<>(supplier, lifespan);
            cachedAttributes.put(category, cachedObject);
        }
        return (T)cachedAttributes.get(category).get();
    }
```

Comment: Not in the standard library. There might be third party libraries that offer an API like this, but realistically it's just going to be similar to what you've implemented here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more generic problem that requires higher order generics. A type variable represents an actual type: `public <T> void foo(T in, T out)` means that the T is a variable and is to be replaced by an actual type. Just like in `void foo(int x)`, x is a variable and is to be replaced, for any given invocation, by an actual `int`.

What this requires is yet another abstractive layer deeper: We now want a type variable, say, ß, which gets replaced not with an actual type, but with a type variable - or at least the notion that you can *declare* type variables within a generics signature block. Something like:

```
Map<{ß} Class<ß>, CachedObject<ß>> cachedAttributes = ...;
```

It's not that `ß` is the same type throughout. ß is different for every k/v pair. Hence, it's a higher order thing.

Java doesn't have this. **What you want is not possible**. Given the steady stream of complaints that generics are 'too complicated' and the questions e.g. here on SO about it, it's probably correct that java does not have them.

There are fixes. One of them is what you've done: That you take some source file and limit the heap violations solely to that source file: That is the one that contains a bunch of `@SuppressWarnings`, unsafe casts, and so on - and requires extra scrutiny on review to ensure that from the outside it is not actually possible to cause generics breaks, so that no other code needs to be infected with it. `ArrayList`, itself, works just the same way: ArrayList's backing store is `Object[]`. Not `T[]` (for good reasons). e.g. the `get(int idx)` method casts to T, which causes a warning, which is suppressed, which is fine, because non-Ts cannot actually end up in that list unless the caller themselves have ignored compiler warnings about generics issues.

There are some takes on this, it comes up relatively often. For example, guava's [ClassToInstanceMap](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html).

Comment: category.cast instead of (T) seems to have hidden the warning. I think this is only due to there being a ClassCastException catch internal to it though.

Comment: It does, and it 'works', but as a principle it doesn't extend all that far. After all, imagine you want T to be `List<String>`. You can't put that in `Class<X>` terms. You can hack it, sure. It won't get you type safety though.

Answer (score 0):

As dan1st pointed out, this is covered in [Java map, key = class, value = instance of that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194855/java-map-key-class-value-instance-of-that-class)

Specifically, replacing `return (T)cachedAttributes.get(category).get();` with  `return category.cast(cachedAttributes.get(category).get());` removed the warning. It seems odd to me though, I feel like there should still be a warning here, as nothing is informing the compiler that wildcards for `Class<?>, CachedObject<?>` are the same.

I will leave this post unanswered for now just in case a more complete answer comes around.